# VirtualBox wrong screen resolution

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I have a problem with my VirtualBox machine for Linux Ubuntu. I installed Windows 7 on my virtualBox machine, I have a Lenovo thinkpad x230, primarily using linux, but I also need Windows for some school projects and homeworks. The problem is I can not set the resolution 1366x768 in my virtual machine.

When I set up the machine in the section display I moved a slider to 256 MB, it is an Intel HD 4000 graphic card. There are 5 resoultions Windows offers me,  1024x768 suits the height of the creen but is centered and there is a huge black gap on both sides.

I tried going to advanced settings in screen resolution to check "Hide all modes display can't show..." but that box is grayed and I can not set my resolution manually. Please, anyone help ASAP. I can work like this but anyone who has this laptop knows how small the display is, and now VirtualBox is making it even smaller.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to install "VirtualBox Guest Additions" on your Windows 7 guest.

Fire up you Windows 7 machine. Navigate to the top of the screen and click on "Devices". 
In that window, click on "Insert Guest Additions CD image". This will mount the VirtualBox Guest Additions CD as a drive for installation.

The program may open by itself, but if not, navigate on the, so called, disc to "VBoxWindowsAdditions" .exe file or your architecture (amd64 or x86) .exe file, and double click it. This will install all the drivers you need to run your Windows 7 guest. You now will be able to run your VirtualBox full screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped, after rebooting my Win on VirtualBox it automatically chose the resolution that fits my screen. Best wishes man <3 <3

Comment: Glad to hear it.